# Repacing NAs before a non-zero value to a zero and replacing zeros after a non-zero values to NAs in r

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, dplyr, subset

*I have a big dataset and I would like to replace all the NAs in every row which appears before a non-zero value AND also replace zeros which appear after non-zero numbers to NA. I have ries this but it didnt work out well.*

### replacing NAs with 0s

```
    n <- min(which(is.na()) - 1
    x[1:n] <- 0
    x
}))
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example as input and your expected output.

Comment: @akrum this is my dataframe

Comment: # input
df2_ <- data.frame(
  ID=c(22,  23, "kk3", 61, "ss22"),
  Info1=c("cd",  "qm", "jj", "fl", "kn"), 
  Info2=c("c1",  "q2", "j3", "f4", "k5"),
  dcol1=c(NA, 20, NA, 0, NA),
  dcol2=c(15, NA, 22, 53, 0), 
  dcol3=c(NA, 50, 0, 0, NA),
  dcol5=c(0, 0, 0, NA, 0))
df2_

output_df2_
ID Info1 Info2 dcol1 dcol2 dcol3 dcol5
1   22    cd    c1     0    15    NA    NA
2   23    qm    q2    20     0    50    NA
3  kk3    jj    j3     0    22    NA    NA
4   61    fl    f4     0    53    NA    NA
5 ss22    kn    k5    NA    NA    NA    NA

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of the fact that in general, this replacement in the way you asked for DOES depend on the order it is executed; please adjust the solution according to your means and/or store the intermediate steps in a temporary dataframe.

(I tried to replicate your datastructure in `df`)

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- matrix(sample.int(20, size = 80, replace = T), nrow = 10)
df[df > 15] <- NA
df[df < 5] <- 0
df <- as.data.frame(df)

# replace all NAs in every row which appear before a non-zero value
df[1:(nrow(df) - 1), ][is.na(df[1:(nrow(df) - 1), ]) & df[2:nrow(df), ] != 0] <- 100

# replace all zeros which appear after non-zero numbers to NA
df[2:nrow(df),][df[1:(nrow(df) - 1),] != 0 & df[2:nrow(df),] == 0] <- NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tried the code, it replaces zeros which come at the first non zero values only but does not replace such zeros which also appear before other non zero values along the row. the best is eg NA 23 NA 45 0 34  NA = 0 23 0 45 0 34 0 but in a data frame not a vector  NOT        NA 23 NA 45 0 34 NA = 0 23 NA 45 0 34 0

Comment: You probably should clarify what mean with "before"; normally in R before is seen in column direction.